# Using AWS::CodeBuild::Project Environment variable in cloudformation template of repository

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codebuild, aws-sam

I want to create a continous delivery pipeline for a Lambda function.

As shown in this [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/build-pipeline.html#setup-repository), the custom environment variables of [`AWS::CodeBuild::Project`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-codebuild-project.html#cfn-codebuild-project-environment) can be used in `buildspec.yaml` like:

```
aws cloudformation package --template-file template.yaml --s3-bucket $MYEVVARKEY --output-template-file outputtemplate.yaml
```

Wanted to use those CodeBuild Project environment variables in the [SAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/serverless_app.html) template of the repository also. As shown below, I tried with dollar signs, but it did not get it as a key but as a text as it is:

```
# template.yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Resources:
  TimeFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: $MY_FN_NAME_ENV_VAR
      Role: $MY_ROLE_ARN_ENV_VAR
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs8.10
      CodeUri: ./
```

So, is it possible to utilize CodeBuild Project environment variables in SAM template, if so what's the notation required to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CloudFormation can't refer to environment variables, doesn't matter SAM or plain. What you can do is to pass environment variables as parameters via shell in CodeBuild `buildspec.yaml` file (`--parameters ParameterKey=name,ParameterValue=${MY_ENV_VAR}`).

Remember to add corresponding parameter to your `Parameters` section.

If you use `aws cloudformation deploy` then you should use `--parameter-overrides`, which is a little simpler form:

```
--parameter-overrides \
    YourParam=${YOUR_ENV_VAR} \
    Foo=Bar \
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you tell where this `parameters` flag can be used? [AWS CLI docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/package.html#synopsis) for `aws cloudformation package`  do not bring it as an option.

Comment: `package` only processes the template and resolves deployment package references. You afterwards need to call `deploy`, which actually executes the template and this is the moment when you pass parameters. I edited answer to include SAM parameter.

Comment: Yes, I use `cloudformation deploy` and the addendum appears to be what I was sought for 